# Google Maps APIs in iPhone Paid App

Tags: ios, google-maps

I want to develop an iPhone Application which uses Google Places API ,The Google Distance Matrix API and The Google Directions API (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/) to find nearby places such as Restaurants,Hospitals etc.

Can I use these three APIs (Google Places API ,The Google Distance Matrix API and The Google Directions API) for free (**without** a Maps API Premier license) in the following

1. Paid iPhone App
2. Free iPhone App **which contains** features that uses these three Google APIs and unlocks additional paid features that **does not use** these APIs, through  in-app purchases.
3. Free iPhone App which unlocks additional paid features that **uses** these Google APIs through in-app purchases

Comment: These API's are freely provided by google so you don't need to worry about it, they have alot of money

Comment: @robin Their web API actually has a restriction on usage in sites that require paid registration. Fortunately, Apple and Google made a deal where Google Maps is a part of the iOS SDK, paid or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to use the apis however a ["powered by google"](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) logo is required