# Can I use Google Maps driving directions in a paid iPhone App?

Tags: google-maps, ios5

I understand that I can use MapKit within a paid iPhone app. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282633/google-maps-apis-in-iphone-paid-app)

How about if I have a feature within such an app that accesses Google Maps driving directions, using Google's web API? Can I still charge for my app?

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444678/do-commercial-paid-iphone-apps-have-to-pay-a-license-to-google-for-maps

Answer (score 1):

The Developer Guide provides you with the info you need:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/usage.html

It's limited to 25 000 map loads per day, as you are making an iPhone App that makes use of Google Maps per user and not through a server, you should be fine unless the user loads a map more then 25.000 a day, then he is being cut of. But this should not effect your commercial intensions of your app when using this API.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I think the notice that applies to my case is here, since I want to use the directions web service. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits